# jQuery UI bounce effect not working but shake does

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bounce

I have the jQuery shake effect working but for some reason when I switch the bounce effect, on mouseover of the element I want to affect, it moves but does not bounce.

```
<div class="thumb-shadow">
    <a href="services/solar">
         <img width="160" height="160" alt="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://localhost:81/dcdccd/cms/wp-content/uploads/solar.jpg" style="">                           
    </a>
</div>

jQuery('.thumb-shadow img').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).effect("bounce", {times: 3}, 500);
});
```

Something I am overlooking?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this...

Comment: it bounces here, http://jsfiddle.net/cYhyc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYhyc/) provided by Spokey works.

My conclusion is, you're not including [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/).

Try adding it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

From your *comments*,

***Might missed to check it*** [image]

Comment: Thanks but jQuery UI is included hence "shake" working. Could it be a version problem?

Comment: @SixfootJames May be.  if you check this link http://jqueryui.com/download/.  you might missed to check the bounce effect before downloading.

Comment: Thanks User! I overlooked that option.

Comment: Yes correct!!! Look at this article for more option http://codingstuffsbykiran.blogspot.in/2009/10/jquery-shake-effect.html